# How to send JWT token to node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, jwt

I wrote a small node.js server with a login system and I am trying to protect my routes. I have created the middleware that should check authentication on each protected route, but it seems that I am not sending the JWT token correctly, because every time I log in I get  the `Authentication failed` message. How can I send the JWT token correctly and log in if the password and username are correct? Here is my Node.js server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 1337;
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const checkAuth = require('./middleware/check-auth.js')
let Post = require('./models/post.model.js');

app.use(cors());
app.use("/assets", express.static(__dirname + "/assets"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('view-engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let username = req.body.username;
    let password = req.body.password;


    if (username !== process.env.USER_NAME && password !== process.env.USER_PASSWORD) {
        res.json('Invalid credentials');

    } else {
        const token = jwt.sign({
            username: username,
        }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: '1h'
        });

        res.redirect(`/dashboard?token=${token}`);
    }
});

app.get('/dashboard', checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.render('dashboard.ejs');
});

app.get('/dashboard/createPost', checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.render('post.ejs');
});

app.post('/dashboard/createPost', async (req, res) => {
    let collection = connection.collection(process.env.POSTS_WITH_TAGS);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let post = new Post(req.body);
    collection.insertOne(post)
        .then(post => {
            res.redirect('/dashboard')
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send(err);
        });
});

app.listen(PORT);
```

and here is my check-auth middleware:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        console.log(token);
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, null);
        req.body.decoded = decoded;
        console.log(req.body.decoded);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Authentication failed'
        });
    }
    next();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript `fetch` API for sending JWT token as `header` authorization

```js
fetch('backend_domain/dashboard', {
     method: 'get',
     headers: {
       Authorization: JWT_Token
     }
}).then(data => {..your operation here..})
```

Reference: [fetch_mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#:%7E:text=The%20Fetch%20API%20provides%20a,such%20as%20requests%20and%20responses.&text=Fetch%20also%20provides%20a%20single,CORS%20and%20extensions%20to%20HTTP.) for better understanding of `fetch` API

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are getting an empty object in req.body when you try to pass it as a json string in postman. I would recommend either

1. pass your credentials in x-www-form-urlencoded tag in postman or
2. Using express.Router() and creating different files for routes

In your index.js file write:

```
app.use('/', require('./routes.js'))
```

And create a file with name routes.js and put your routes as this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
 let username = req.body.username;
 let password = req.body.password;

console.log(req.body);
 if (username !== process.env.USER_NAME && password !== process.env.USER_PASSWORD) {
     res.json('Invalid credentials');

 } else {
     const token = jwt.sign({
         username: username
     }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
         expiresIn: 3600
     });

     return res.send({token});
 }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: That way the user does not get redirected to the page after the token is sent, that is why I sent it like this:  res.redirect(`/dashboard?token=${token}`); and I cant send two responses.

Comment: so instead of res.send({token}) just return res.redirect in router